# Term for the request for reimbursement from an employer

Tags: word-choice, terminology

We have this system where we buy what we see fit and later fill out a form requesting that our employer pay back the expenses. I'm pretty sure there's a special term for it in English.

I'd also like to know if there are different names for such a form: a formal and official one as well as a colloquial, commonly used one.

Moreover, I'd like to know if those terms (both categories) are the same on both sides of the Sargasso Sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "expense claim". I've seen it used widely in the UK and USA.

Comment: In the US, the "claim" is usually conveyed via an *expense report*.

Comment: "expense report" is used, but in my company (in the US office) "expense report" is the thing finance people run to see how many "expense claims" have been submitted and need review and approval. But I'm just a single data point; other US companies may do as you suggest. It wouldn't be the first time the US got English wrong ;-)

Comment: Both _claim form_ and _reimbursement form_ are also widely used. You might also see _reimbursement request_.